# Dropdownlist to enter and select date

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to enter date (for eg:`02-jan-2011`) in dropdownlist and depending on the selected date i need to display data in gridview on the dropdownlist's selected index changed. Also this dropdown is used to insert date in database and also to select date from database. Intellisense should work while user type a date which is in database.

Thanks

Comment: why don't we do all your job.. dude, what the hell!

Comment: as you can probably tell from the comments, your question is unclear and overly broad.  Try to narrow it down to a specific issue, e.g.: "_I've got a drop-down list and I'd like to use it to filter a grid view, here's my code so far._"  If you're just looking for someone to complete a project for you, you'd be better off somewhere like [here](http://www.getacoder.com/).

Comment: It is obvious that you have not done your homework and you want someone else to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking something like...

```
String date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"); // Format your Date string
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(date, date)); // Adding formatted date into Dropdownlist
```

Comment: what about intellisense (option of  date which is in database)?

Comment: You can iterate the resultant rows, set format and then add as an item in dropdownlist.